# Banno - Is there any way to deep link directly into a Banno plugin's expanded view?

Tags: banno-digital-toolkit

We want to link directly into the expanded view of a Banno plugin from an email.

Is this possible?

Are there any ways to pass parameters (ie. queryParams) from the JH Dashboard into a plugin extension?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

We currently configure params via the extension settings, however, we'd like to be able to dynamically pass in parameters.

Answer (score 0):

> We want to link directly into the expanded view of a Banno plugin from an email.
>
> Is this possible?

No, there isn't any support for deep linking into the Expanded View of a plugin card.

> Are there any ways to pass parameters (ie. queryParams) from the JH Dashboard into a plugin extension?
>
> ...
> We currently configure params via the extension settings, however, we'd like to be able to dynamically pass in parameters.

There isn't anything you could do in terms of sending parameters via an external link (e.g. from an email as asked about above).

Somewhat related: I'm not sure exactly what you intend in terms of 'dynamic parameters' but the Plugin Bridge provides some [flexibility in terms of routing HTML anchor tags](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/architecture/userinterface/banno-plugin-framework-bridge/).

- We also have materials on the difference between using the Plugin Bridge compared to using a configured primary action button to activate the Expanded View from a plugin's Card Face [Designing and Developing Plugins](https://jackhenry.dev/open-api-docs/plugins/guides/designinganddevelopingplugins/) guide.